# Custom Build Tool only builds one item each time I build the project

Tags: visual-studio

OK, bit of a weird one - I have a batch file which converts a .svg file into a header file, like so:

`svg_header.bat`

```
echo %1 -> %2
@(
    echo const char *%~n1_svg = R"***(
    type %~1
    echo ^)***";
) > %~2
```

So, for example, if I have `images\normal.svg` I can go

`svg_header.bat images\normal.svg images\normal_svg.h`

And the resulting header file can be included in a C++ source file like so

`#include "images\\normal_svg.h"`

So far so good.

In my Visual Studio project, I have added 3 .svg files and specified a Custom Build Tool for them as follows:

[image: Custom Build Tool Property Page]

The strange thing is that each time I build the project, it only works for *one* of the files.

So the output looks like this:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: mic_muter, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>SVG to Header microphone_mute
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "images\microphone_normal.svg" succeeded, but specified output "u:\dev\hid_kbd\mic_muter\mic_muter\images\microphone_normal_svg.h" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): warning MSB8065: Custom build for item "images\microphone_base.svg" succeeded, but specified output "u:\dev\hid_kbd\mic_muter\mic_muter\images\microphone_base_svg.h" has not been created. This may cause incremental build to work incorrectly.
1>mic_muter.cpp
1>U:\dev\hid_kbd\mic_muter\mic_muter\mic_muter.cpp(5,10): fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'images/microphone_normal_svg.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "mic_muter.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I build the project again, the next file will be converted but the 3rd one fails with the same error. Building for a third time gets the last one and the build succeeds.

Does anyone understand what's going on here? I've tried basically every combination of all the different fields in the Custom Build Tool property page, but the same behaviour persists.

The .vcxproj section for each file is identical (apart from the source filename) and looks like this:

```
    <CustomBuild Include="images\microphone_mute.svg">
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">false</DeploymentContent>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</DeploymentContent>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</DeploymentContent>
      <DeploymentContent Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">false</DeploymentContent>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">SVG to Header %(Filename)</Message>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">SVG to Header %(Filename)</Message>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">SVG to Header %(Filename)</Message>
      <Message Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">SVG to Header %(Filename)</Message>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">$(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">$(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h</Command>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat</AdditionalInputs>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat</AdditionalInputs>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat</AdditionalInputs>
      <AdditionalInputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat</AdditionalInputs>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">false</LinkObjects>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">false</LinkObjects>
      <LinkObjects Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">false</LinkObjects>
      <OutputItemType Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">ClInclude</OutputItemType>
      <OutputItemType Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">ClInclude</OutputItemType>
      <OutputItemType Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">ClInclude</OutputItemType>
      <OutputItemType Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">ClInclude</OutputItemType>
      <VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">true</VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist>
      <VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">true</VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist>
      <VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">true</VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist>
      <VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">true</VerifyInputsAndOutputsExist>
    </CustomBuild>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this problem today, moving from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2022.

Using the MSB8065 or MSB8064 warning codes as keywords did not help finding an explanation on what was wrong but this [old post from MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/939c41ed-48d7-437b-a1f9-c888c93f1c87/custom-build-tool-file-level-vs2008-worked-fine-vs2010-only-1-fires) explains that you need to prepend your custom build command using the `call` command if it invokes a batch file.

In your example that would mean writing:

```
call $(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h
```

instead of

```
$(ProjectDir)svg_to_header.bat %(FullPath) $(ProjectDir)images\%(Filename)_svg.h
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: You probably just saved my a day of work. Thanks!